# script não escreve em arquivo

Tags: linux, bash

Estou montando um bash script da seguinte forma:

```
#!/bin/bash

destfile=/home/user/teste.txt
array=($(ls 20151* |awk '{ print $9 }'))
n=${array[@]}

echo "$n" > "$destfile"
```

porém ao executar o script o arquivo teste.txt é criado, mas vazio. Só que se executo os comandos um a um no terminal, o arquivo é criado com o conteúdo, exatamente da forma que preciso. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: seu problema certamente está nessa linha: ($(ls 20151* |awk '{ print $9 }')) Tem como você postar alguns exemplos dos nomes dos arquivos que comecam com 20151*? Poste o nome do arquivo todo, inclusive com a extensão, se houver.

Comment: esta não é a questão, pois todos os nomes de arquivos estão basicamente neste formato: "20151223152832_alexsandro_felix.txt"

Comment: Veja só, eu não sei como isso pode ter funcionando executando manual como você disse, pois ao fazer o awk '{ print $9 }' no nome do arquivo 20151223152832_alexsandro_felix.txt realmente não pode retornar nada. Só funcionaria dessa maneira se, por exemplo, sua string tivesse 9 espaços em branco no nome do arquivo. Aí sim o awk imprimiria a 9a posição desse "vetor".

Comment: Poste o que você deseja de retorno que aí fica mais fácil ajudar. Qual deve ser o contéudo do arquivo teste.txt baseado nesse padrão de nome de arquivo que você tem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, o `awk` faz um split em uma string usando o caracter de espaço em branco como separador.

Portanto, se isso for feito:

```
echo "20151223152832_alexsandro_felix.txt" | awk '{print $9}'
```

nada será retornado, pois não existe qualquer espaço em branco na string e, mesmo que tivesse, seriam necessários 8 espaços para que o print na posição 9 retornasse algo.

Experimente agora mudar a string, incluindo um espaço em branco:

```
echo "20151223152832 _alexsandro_felix.txt" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Será retornado: `20151223152832`

```
echo "20151223152832 _alexsandro_felix.txt" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Será retornado: `_alexsandro_felix.txt`

O comando `ls -lh` retorna uma string nesse formato:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cantoni cantoni 0 Jan 12 10:39 20151223152832_alexsandro_felix.txt
```

Por isso, ao fazer um `awk '{print $9}'` o nome do arquivo é impresso. O perigo dessa abordagem é se o nome do arquivo contiver espaços. Se isso acontecer, então o `awk '{print $9}'` não retornará o nome do arquivo todo.

Explicado isso, uma forma de resolver esse problema sem usar o `awk` seria usando o seguinte comando:

```
ls -A 20151*
```

No contexto do problema da pergunta seria isso:

```
array=($(ls -A 20151*));
```

É possível mudar o separador pelo qual o `awk` faz o split em uma string, veja exemplo abaixo:

```
echo "20151223152832:_alexsandro_felix.txt" | awk -F':' '{print $2}'
```

Será retornado: `_alexsandro_felix.txt`

Nesse caso, o separador foi o caracter `':'`

Answer (score 2):

descobri meu erro, na verdade como tenho em meu usuário um alias para o ls eu acabei me acostumando com ele, então realmente o erro estava na linha que o @cantoni citou. Para corrigir fiz da seguinte forma:

```
#!/bin/bash

destfile=/home/user/file.txt;
array=($(ls -lh 20151* |awk '{ print $9 }'));
n=${#array[@]};

echo "$n" > "$destfile";
```

Comment: Então no final você queria apenas o nome do arquivo. :-)

Comment: nesta parte do script que estava dando o problema sim, porém ele é um pouco mais extenso. (ao final, para o que precisava acabei nem usando o awk. Montei o array com um find filtrando os arquivos por data). De toda forma, muito obrigado a todos.

Comment: no fundo o que queres é `ls -1 > ~/file.txt` ?